# How to change variable mentioned in input string?

Tags: c++

I have a student's project for school, I'm mostly programming in PHP, so C++ is not a my strong side :) Please let me know, is it possible to change variable which I mention in cin string? Maybe my code below will be more understandable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, R, Q, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z;
string instrukcja;
string krok[3];
int i = 0;

string MAKENULL()
{
    return " ";
}

void WRITE(string x)
{
    cout << x;
}

int main()
{   
    // get instruction Begin
    char s[10];
    scanf("%10[0-9a-zA-Z ]", s);
    istringstream iss(s);
    while(iss)
    {
        string sub;
        iss >> sub;
        krok[i] = sub;
        i++;
    }
    // get instruction End


    if (krok[0] == "MAKENULL")
    {
        "" Variable in krok[1] "" = MAKENULL();
    }

    if (krok[0] == "WRITE")
    {
        WRITE("" Variable in krok[1] "");
    }

    if (krok[0] == "OPPOSITE")
    {
        OPPOSITE("" Variable in krok[1] "", "" Variable in krok[2] "")
    }

}
```

In code above I will do something like ADD A B, and A should became A => A+B (one string stick to the other). Main question is, can I point a variable to change in scanf?

Comment: Its not really clear what you want to do. You want to concatenate two strings? and what is `OPPOSITE()` ?

Comment: Maybe I will try to explatin whole project. There will be registers (A-Z), and this program will only get one input (in loop) with instruction (like ADD A, Z; OPPOSITE A, W; WRITE A etc...) and that I need now is can I point in scanf/cin a specific variable to change?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you have to provide some mapping from the string representations ("A","B"...) to the variables holding the values (ie. the `string A,B,...`). You could use a `std::map<std::string,std::string>` where the key is the `string` that you get from `scanf` and the value (i.e. the second string in the map) is the value that you want to modify

Comment: Example: if I write CREATE A qwerty, A should become qwerty (A = "qwerty"), if I write then OPPOSITE A, A should become ytrewq (A = "ytrewq")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly then instead of keeping variables as now A,B,C,... you need a [map container](http://pl.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
#include <map>
// ...
std::map<std::string, std::string> varMap;
```

where key is the variable name: A,B,C and value is a its value.

Then you can use your current way of reading, when you assign value to variable A, then you use:

```
varMap["A"] = newValue;
```

and when you read it you also use `std::string value = varMap["A"]`, but be carefull here, if "A" does not exist in map it will be created and value initialized (default constructor is called - so that it will be empty string). To check if key exsists use `if (varMap.find("A") == varMap.end()) {/*no such variable*/}`

Another thing is that you istringstream usage is wrong you should check if something was read before using it, the proper idiom is:

```
istringstream iss(s);
string sub;
while(iss >> sub)
{
    krok[i] = sub;
    i++;
}
```

[edit]

What you probably had in mind was a possibility to use php like [variable variables concept](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), or reflection from java and other languages. There is no such thing in c++, and the recomended way - as also in php is to use associative container like map.

Comment: It might work... I will try and give feedback :) Thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly, it is some kind of array, but instead of numbers, there are chars, right?

Comment: `Associative container` - but you might think of this as an array with `std::string` as indexes.